# Using NIntegrate over 1 variable to find function of 2 variables

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm attempting to numerically solve the following in order to get a function of 2 variables, just looking at the real part of

$$\psi(x,t)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{2}}\int_{-100}^{100}\frac{\sin{(k)}}{k}e^{i\left[kx-\frac{k^2}{2}t\right]}\,dk$$

where I have specific values for $t=0,2,4$ and I'd like to plot the function from $x=-10$ to $x=10$. The way I've tried so far is

```
func[x_, t_] := Re[Sin[k]/k*Exp[I*(k*x - k^2/2*t)]]
y = Table[NIntegrate[func[x, 0], {k, -100, 100}], {x, -10, 10, 0.01}]
```

I get several errors when running this but still get some results out

[image]

The plotted results aren't what I was expecting. I've done this numerical integration in Matlab where I specified in the integration function to expect an array:

```
x=-10:0.01:10;
func = @(k,c) sin(k)./(pi*sqrt(2).*k).*cos(k.*c-k.^2./2*0);
real_0 = integral(@(k)func(k,x),-100,100,'ArrayValued',true);
```

I'm pretty new to Mathematica and don't know what the equivalent to this Matlab expression would be.

Here are the results I get from Mathematica

[image]

and what I get from Matlab

[image]

Comment: They look like they might be the same to me. In the Mathematica code where you plot the graph (I assume you use something like `ListLinePlot`) add a line that says `PlotRange -> Full` in order to see the full graph. Mathematica tends to zoom in so that you don't miss seeing "interesting" behaviour near the x-axis.

Comment: @MassDefect that did the trick, I didn't even realize I wasn't seeing the whole graph!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your plot is that did not use `PlotRange->All`.

First slight modifications of your `NIntegrate` code:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 xs = Range[-10, 10, 0.01]; 
 ys = Table[
   NIntegrate[func[x, 0], {k, -100, 100}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 100,
    PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 4], {x, xs}];
 ]

(* {42.5655, Null} *)
```

(The precision goal change from 6 to 4 does not have significant effect on the computation speed; the accuracy goal change to 4 does.)

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xs, ys}], PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: I see how not using PlotRange -> All would affect my plot. When I did your approach I still got some NIntegrate and General errors, although not as many as when I attempted my first approach. Are these things to worry about or can they safely be ignored?

Comment: I only saw warning messages. As far as I know MATLAB uses local adaptive integration strategy (or at least it did 12 years ago.) So, you can use `NIntegrate`'s "LocalAdaptive" method and you will get less number of messages or none. E.g. try this: `ys = Table[
  NIntegrate[func[x, 0], {k, -100, 100}, 
   Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 100], {x, 
   xs}]`

Comment: This is really helpful, I was getting some pretty jagged plots but using the LocalAdaptive strategy makes the data look much better! Thanks @AntonAntonov